Is there any way to automatically Set Origin > Origin to Geometry when importing an STL file?
I import a lot of STL files to digitally assemble models for 3D printing.
99.9% of the time I set Origin to Geometry as soon as I import any STL file.
Is there a way to tell Blender I want that to be done automatically as soon as I import an STL file?
